# Convert JSONB field from single value to object with own keys

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table, let's call it myTable with the following structure

```
ID   | data
____________
uuid | jsonb
```

The data in the jsonb field is an array structured in the following way:

```
[
  {
    "valueA": "500",
    "valueB": "ABC",
  },
  {
    "valueA": "300",
    "valueB": "CDE",
  }
]
```

What I want to do is transform that data by converting valueB to be an object, with newKey that corresposnds to the current value of "valueB"

This is the result I want:

```
[
  {
    "valueA": "500",
    "valueB": {"newKey": "ABC"},
  },
  {
    "valueA": "300",
    "valueB": {"newKey": "CDE"},
  }
]
```

I tried doing it with the following query:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET data = (
    SELECT jsonb_agg (
        jsonb_insert(elems, '{valueB, newKey}', elems->'valueB')
    )
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) elems
);
```

It doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately.

Another idea I have is to create a new field, initialize it as an object, then delete the old onde and rename the new one, but it seems there must be a way to do what I want directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using [jsonb_build_object()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)

```
UPDATE myTable
SET data = (
    SELECT jsonb_agg (
        jsonb_insert(elems, '{valueB}', jsonb_build_object('newKey', elems->'valueB'))
    )
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) elems
);
```